# GCP App Engine: Handling signal: term + Worker exiting after each request

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, gunicorn

I'm deploying a small flask app on GCP App Engine but it seems gunicorn is shutting down immediately after each request. I'm using a user session and a connection to an API (atproto), but I can't stay logged because it always disconnects the user.

I read some similar issues are caused by sending big files, doing long requests or whatever, but that's not the case here, when I run the app on my computer everything is instantaneous.

Here is the log I get after the first request when I get on the home page. The "/" and the following line are prints from the python function. 2 seconds after that, the worker are exiting.

```
2023-09-25 12:15:42 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:42 +0000] [11] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2023-09-25 12:15:42 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:42 +0000] [11] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (11)
2023-09-25 12:15:42 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:42 +0000] [11] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
2023-09-25 12:15:43 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:42 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
2023-09-25 12:15:43 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:43 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
2023-09-25 12:15:43 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:43 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
2023-09-25 12:15:43 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:43 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
2023-09-25 12:15:52 default[20230925t120108]  / 
2023-09-25 12:15:52 default[20230925t120108]  Utilisateur non connecté, chargement de la page de connexion
2023-09-25 12:15:54 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:54 +0000] [11] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2023-09-25 12:15:54 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:54 +0000] [22] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22)
2023-09-25 12:15:54 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:54 +0000] [23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23)
2023-09-25 12:15:54 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:54 +0000] [24] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24)
2023-09-25 12:15:54 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:54 +0000] [19] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19)
2023-09-25 12:15:55 default[20230925t120108]  [2023-09-25 12:15:55 +0000] [11] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
```

What could be causing that ? Do I have to configure gunicorn and how ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a number of reasons, Gunicorn may be terminating itself after each request on GCP App Engine:

- Scaling down the App Engine instance to zero.
- Gunicorn is set up to terminate itself following each request.
- It crashes because of a flaw in either your programme or `gunicorn`.

To troubleshoot the issue, you can check the App Engine logs, check the `gunicorn` configuration, or debug your app.

The following advice can be used to configure `gunicorn` on GCP App Engine:

- Use the `--preload` flag to improve the startup time of the App Engine instance and reduce the delay in the response to the first request.
- Use the `--daemon` flag to cause Gunicorn to run in the background. This can be helpful for preventing the App Engine instance from being scaled down to zero.
- Use the `--workers` flag to specify the number of worker processes to create. You can adjust this setting based on the expected traffic load to your app.
- Use the `--timeout` flag to specify the maximum amount of time that a worker process should spend handling a request. If a request takes longer than this time to complete, the worker process will be restarted.